# Android sliding tabs, Fragment_Collection_Object Error

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

am following the Android Developers website to add sliding tabs to my Android app for my project, I am stuck with this one error and do not understand the problem, I know it has something to do with calling the correct Fragment layout, I am doing exactly what the tutorial tells me too, have any of you guys got any information to solve this, thank you.

```
package com.test.finalproject;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

DemoCollectionPagerAdapter mCollectionPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;


Button buttonLogin;
Button buttonRegister;
Button buttonTheme;
Button buttonMaps;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Utils.setThemeToActivity(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);



 // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // show the given tab
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // hide the given tab
        }

        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // probably ignore this event
        }
    };

    // Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText("Tab " + (i + 1))
                        .setTabListener(tabListener));
    }




    buttonLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonTheme = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonTheme);
    buttonTheme.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonMaps = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps);
    buttonMaps.setOnClickListener(this);

    mCollectionPagerAdapter =
            new DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(
                    getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);

}




public class DemoCollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new DemoObjectFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        // Our object is just an integer :-P
        args.putInt(DemoObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
    }
}



public static class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // The last two arguments ensure LayoutParams are inflated
        // properly.
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
```

> > > > > > > > ```
> > > > > > > >              R.layout.fragment_collection_object, container, false);
> > > > > > > >         Bundle args = getArguments();
> > > > > > > >         ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
> > > > > > > >                 Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT)));
> > > > > > > >         return rootView;
> > > > > > > >     }
> > > > > > > > }
> > > > > > > > ```

```
public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
            new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // When swiping between pages, select the
                    // corresponding tab.
                    getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

}




private void buttonLoginClick()
{
    startActivity (new Intent("MainApp"));
}

private void buttonRegisterClick()
{
    startActivity (new Intent("TextToo"));
}

private void buttonThemeClick()
{
    startActivity (new Intent("SettingsTheme"));
}

private void buttonMapsClick()
{
    startActivity (new Intent("GoogleMaps"));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.buttonLogin:
            buttonLoginClick();
            break;

    }
    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.buttonRegister:
        buttonRegisterClick();
        break;
    }
    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.buttonTheme:
        buttonThemeClick();
        break;
    }

    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.buttonMaps:
        buttonMapsClick();
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

The Error is on line 126.

The Error is: Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
fragment_collection_object cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java   /Login/src/com/test/finalproject    line 126    Java Problem

Comment: You may want to highlight the code that causes the error and the error you are getting.

Comment: I edited the question, the line that says .layout.fragment_collection_object, container, false);

Comment: Sounds like the xml is missing from that, but I guess its more complicated.

Comment: You may want to use the sdk demo instead of tryingtryint to follow the tutorial. They often require background knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because of the missing xml file in the layout folder of project/res

Go to http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html
Click on "download the sample app" and unzip it. Add the EffectiveNavigation\res\layout\fragment_collection_object.xml to you project\res\layout. This,I guess will solve the problem.